# Android - Where are custom APK files stored?

Tags: android, eclipse

So I messed up. I removed some apps from my eclipse workspace (all related just large) so I went to go pull in another app to modify it a bit and eclipse errored brining it in wiping all of the files still there but 0kb. Tried my handy dandy recovery app with no luck.

But the apk is still on my dev phone. Is there a way to get it off of my dev phone? I already checked and it's not in System/App...

Phone is a Nexus 4 running ICS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/data/app is where youll find the apk.

Note that you arent getting the source, just the apk file. I dont see how this will help in Eclipse at all.

Comment: Also note that you need to have root access to view this directory.

Comment: if hes looking in system/app/, hes probablay already aware, but yes. anything outside of /sdcard you pretty much need root to much around with.

Comment: You can get source code from an apk. It's not easy, as I remember, but doable with some research

Comment: Decompiling an apk will VERY rarely give you actual usable compilable code. More of just a reference. Please do not pull the apk expecting to be able to pick up development on it where you left off.

Comment: @ArmaAK - you have to be root or *list* the directory, but **not** to *pull* from its contents if you know the exact filename of the installed apk including its likely suffix.

Comment: thats not even kinda true, and makes no logical sense. I can take whatever I want, but cant look? If that behavior is true on your device, PLEASE wipe and reinstall ASAP.